Is there a way to specify hours and days instead of milliseconds for expiry-delay?
<address-setting match="asdf">
  ...
  <expiry-delay>60000</expiry-delay>
  <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
  ...
</address-setting>

Is there any another way to describe hours and days instead of milliseconds in expiry delay? I tried in milliseconds, but I need hours and days to describe expiry-delay.

The expiry-delay setting accepts only a numeric value to define the expiration time in milliseconds.
The only way to specify hours and days is to convert them in milliseconds, i.e. 2 days and 3 hours = 2x24x60x60x1000 + 3x60x60x1000 = 183600000 milliseconds

If getting the hours and days exactly right all the time is essential, please remember that daylight savings changes can mean a day isn't always 24 hours long.
